# Excel formula to get current month in text

Tags: excel, text, formula

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find it anywhere...

When I try to use `=TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"MMMM")`, it returns "January", but I want the current month. It returns "10" when I try `=MONTH(TODAY())`, but adding the TEXT function seems to be messing something up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10 is not a date, or it is a date `Jan 10th, 1900`.  Remove the MONTH part:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")
```

The `"MMMM"` will make the change to the month based on the full date, no need to parse the date yourself.